# How do I sum all the elements from the leaf to the root of each branch in a n-ary tree in OCaml?

Tags: tree, ocaml, n-ary-tree

I'm trying to make a function in OCaml where, given a n-tree, it returns a list of all the sums from leaf to root of all the branches.
This is what i did:

```
exception NotFound

type 'a ntree = Tr of 'a * 'a ntree list

let leaf x = Tr (x, [])

let alb = 
  Tr (1, [Tr (2, [leaf 3; leaf 4; leaf 2]); 
          Tr (5, [leaf 11; leaf 10]); 
          Tr (3, [leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])])

let rec peso (Tr (x, tlist)) =
  match tlist with
    [] -> [x]
  | _ -> [x + peso_l tlist]
and peso_l = function 
    [] -> raise NotFound
  | [t] -> peso t
  | t::rest -> peso t :: peso_l rest
```

But it doesn't work because, I think,

```
| _ ->[x + peso_l tlist]
```

returns something like `[x+ [t]]` (am I right?).
How can I fix it?

Comment: For a given node `n`, use a `List.fold_left` to sum the result of `peso` for all its childs

Comment: This question would be improved with a sample of the expected output, and any errors you received trying to use your code. There are a lot of smart people here, so they can probably figure it out, but making it easier for them to figure it out will probably get you more and better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `[x + peso_l tlist]` what you want to do is add `x` to each element of the list returned by `peso_l tlist`. This can be achieved with `List.map`:

```ml
exception NotFound

type 'a ntree = Tr of 'a * 'a ntree list

let leaf x = Tr (x, [])

let alb =
  Tr
    ( 1,
      [
        Tr (2, [ leaf 3; leaf 4; leaf 2 ]);
        Tr (5, [ leaf 11; leaf 10 ]);
        Tr (3, [ leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10 ]);
      ] )

let rec peso (Tr (x, tlist)) =
  match tlist with [] -> [ x ] | _ -> List.map (( + ) x) (peso_l tlist)
and peso_l = function
  | [] -> raise NotFound
  | [ t ] -> peso t
  | t :: rest -> peso t @ peso_l rest

let () =
  Format.printf "@[<v 0>%a@."
    Format.(
      pp_print_list ~pp_sep:pp_print_cut (fun ppf d ->
          Format.fprintf ppf "%d" d))
    (peso alb)
```

Comment: I was thinking of List.map too, but i had no idea what @ was so i still had errors...thank you

Comment: You're welcome. When you work with a module you don't know, remember to open its documentation. If you don't care about order, List.rev_append is better than @ by the way